Error logging onto virtual machine Because of a protocol error (code: 0x112f)
I had no problem logging into the virtual machine until Thursday now I get
Because of a protocol error (code: 0x112f), the remote session will be disconnected.
Please try connecting to the remote computer again.
Error code: 0x4
Extended error code: 0x112f

I've tried the following things:
Restarting my local machine and the virtual machine
Trying on a different computer
Only using one screen
Changing gpedit.msc WDDM disable on VM and local
Changing environment settings, display settings etc on MS RDC
Changing NIC
Redeploying VM
I am completely out of ideas now. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?


Error logging onto virtual machine Because of a protocol error (code:0x112f)

The above error was encountered due to the resolution. Follow the steps below to resolve the issue

Change the display setting Remote Desktop Connection

Open Remote Desktop Connection > Show Options > Display > Uncheck the option >Use all my monitors for the remote session


Change the local policy Limit number of monitors to match the number of monitors you are using. For example, if you have 1 monitor, set it to 1. After making the changes, reboot the device



Change the performance settings by Uncheck the option Persistent bitmap caching in Remote Desktop Connection.



First try to connect with only one monitor (by uncheck "Use all my monitors for the remote session" in the "Display" tab before connecting the device).

Reference: How to fix Remote desktop connection protocol error 0x112f
protocol error code 0x112f on local machine, solved when logged onto
